# Align Button and EditText on Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have this code as the footer of my listview. Its just an EditText and a Button to send messages.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/relativelayout_messages" android:gravity="right" 
    android:background="@drawable/fondomain" android:paddingTop="4dp">   

<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@layout/linedivider" android:dividerHeight="8dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#0000" android:paddingTop="5dp"  
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:footerDividersEnabled="true" 
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"     
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
 />

<!-- footer -->
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/greytable"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_sent_msg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt_sent_msg" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:text="Enviar"
        android:id="@+id/bt_sent_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@layout/selector_button_msg"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"           
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Ant this is the shape for the button background

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#757202"
            android:endColor="#757202"
            android:angle="270" />    
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#919790"/>   
    </shape>
</item>

<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#FFF038"
            android:endColor="#FFFF6C"
            android:angle="270" />    
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />   
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#919790"/>                   
    </shape>
</item>
```

It's not easy to see at first glance but my EdiTextis not completely align with my Button. As you can see

[image]

Comment: my editText is not completely align with my EdiText??

Comment: please clarify your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do:

1. Set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to both your edittext and button.
2. Set `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` to edittext.
3. Set `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edittextid"` to button.

Adding your modified code for `footer`:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_sent_msg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt_sent_msg" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:text="Enviar"
        android:id="@+id/bt_sent_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Crashes and tell me that I am having circular dependencies. I remove line android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bt_sent_msg" on edittext and doesnt work

Comment: In case of circular dependencies you have given references to two views of each other.

Comment: If I put your code the listview doesnt appear, and instead appears a grey block. But If I remove  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" is the same as before.

Comment: OK, I have modified my main Thread, thanks for your help man!

Comment: Hi Vineet, the code works good but if I dont use android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" on the editText and the button, do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Allign edit text to bottom left corner of the parent. Then allign you button to the right of edit text and allign button top to edit text top and button bottom to edit text bottom