# Listview take full screen In Android

Tags: android, listview, fullscreen, imagebutton

I am new android development. Below i attach my layout file.

In my layout i have one `ListView` and one `EditText` with `ImageButton`. When i insert task in `EditText` and press the `ImageButton` that task will be added in `ListView` one by one.

My problem is suppose i add more than 4 task means the `EditText` with `ImageButton` view is not visible because the list items take that place please give solution thanks...

**Layout:**

```
     <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/frontpagetasklistid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="375dp" >

        </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            >
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextselector"
            android:hint="Add Today Task"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebuttonidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/addtask" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextselector"
        android:hint="Add Today Task"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebuttonidAddTodayTask"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/addtask" />

 </RelativeLayout>
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/frontpagetasklistid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout">

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

or

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/frontpagetasklistid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"         
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_layout">

   </ListView>  

   <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextselector"
        android:hint="Add Today Task"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebuttonidAddTodayTask"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/addtask" />

 </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am guessing that your edittext and imagebutton are below your listview.. In that case you can add this views in listview's footer.. you can google to find how to add views in listview footer

here is a good example:
[Align Button and EditText on Relative Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428368/align-button-and-edittext-on-relative-layout)

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

I have not run the below solution , But you can achieve it by using `layout_weightSum` and `layout_weight` property.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weigthSum="1">

     <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.9">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/frontpagetasklistid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="375dp" >

        </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.1">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            >
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextselector"
            android:hint="Add Today Task"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebuttonidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/addtask" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need to try it, to proof me right, but it should work to put the ListView into a ScrollView with fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**
Try to add your editText and ImageButton like footer:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_above="@+id/lay1">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/frontpagetasklistid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lay1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imagebuttonidAddTodayTask"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/addtask"
     />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ems="10"
     android:background="@drawable/edittextselector"
    android:hint="Add Today Task" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will might help you....

Comment: Try to use my full xml file. And let me know it helps you or not

Comment: check my edited answer. I have tested it and it is working like a charm. Check it out- @Satheesh

Comment: why is needed to have listview inside another Layout?

Comment: this can be a little bit more expensive in terms of drawing, and performance in comparison to the listview added directly to the parent, which could be more cheap and could led to better performance.

Comment: It is a useful design if you gonna make a custom list adapter where you have to deal with other view of parent layout..@Permita

Comment: you can accomplish that even without adding to another layout.  A layout with children that has no siblings, is not a ScrollView or a root layout, and does not have a background, can be removed and have its children moved directly into the parent for a flatter and more efficient layout hierarchy. Check this: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html